# Centos 7 A start job is running rough DKMS

Tags: centos, boot, dkms

When booting on my Linux Centos 7, it stays stuck on the message `A start job is running for Builds a... rough DKMS`
Do you have any idea how to solve it?

---

systemd-analyze blame
gives me the following output:

```
 25.074s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
              8.999s vdo.service
              6.932s kdump.service
              6.536s lvm2-monitor.service
              5.816s systemd-udev-settle.service
              5.112s firewalld.service
              4.737s dev-mapper-centos\x2droot.device
              4.351s postfix.service
              3.683s initrd-switch-root.service
              3.322s gsRunProcessorManager.service
              2.726s microcode.service
              2.549s lvm2-pvscan@8:6.service
              2.484s boot.mount
              2.098s teamviewerd.service
              1.572s smartd.service
              1.528s dracut-initqueue.service
              1.407s home.mount
              1.385s network.service
              1.369s avahi-daemon.service
              1.361s netcf-transaction.service
              1.358s mcelog.service
              1.355s sysstat.service
              1.354s ModemManager.service
              1.350s abrt-ccpp.service
              1.350s vboxdrv.service
              1.346s rhel-dmesg.service
              1.321s chronyd.service
              1.161s polkit.service
              1.122s NetworkManager.service
              1.103s dmraid-activation.service
              1.080s gssproxy.service
              1.067s systemd-udevd.service
               973ms udisks2.service
               958ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
    953ms tuned.service
               951ms systemd-machined.service
               793ms rhel-readonly.service
               666ms dev-loop1.device
               640ms accounts-daemon.service
               611ms systemd-journald.service
               603ms rhel-domainname.service
               422ms systemd-binfmt.service
               396ms rtkit-daemon.service
               393ms kmod-static-nodes.service
               376ms sysroot.mount
               370ms ksm.service
               353ms systemd-sysctl.service
               332ms dev-mqueue.mount
               329ms dev-hugepages.mount
               315ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
               315ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
               305ms auditd.service
               285ms dev-loop2.device
               276ms var-lib-snapd-snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dcore18-32.mount
               270ms systemd-journal-flush.service
               269ms dev-loop3.device
               243ms dev-loop0.device
               242ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
               234ms systemd-remount-fs.service
               198ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
               198ms dracut-cmdline.service
               188ms systemd-logind.service
               167ms dracut-pre-pivot.service
               131ms var-lib-snapd-snap-snapd-8790.mount
               124ms upower.service
               122ms var-lib-snapd-snap-core18-1885.mount
                95ms initrd-parse-etc.service
                92ms colord.service
    91ms libvirtd.service
                91ms dracut-pre-udev.service
                87ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
                84ms systemd-readahead-replay.service
                72ms rhel-import-state.service
                66ms var-lib-snapd-snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount
                51ms var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount
                50ms plymouth-switch-root.service
                43ms sshd.service
                35ms jexec.service
                26ms systemd-readahead-collect.service
                26ms nfs-config.service
                26ms plymouth-read-write.service
                24ms systemd-random-seed.service
                20ms initrd-cleanup.service
                20ms lightdm.service
                18ms plymouth-start.service
                16ms systemd-fsck-root.service
                16ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
                16ms vboxweb-service.service
                16ms dev-mapper-centos\x2dswap.swap
                15ms vboxautostart-service.service
                15ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
                13ms rsyslog.service
                13ms plymouth-quit.service
                10ms ksmtuned.service
                10ms rpc-statd-notify.service
                 9ms rhsmcertd.service
                 9ms iscsi-shutdown.service
                 8ms blk-availability.service
                 7ms initrd-udevadm-cleanup-db.service
                 6ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
                 6ms systemd-update-utmp.service
                 6ms systemd-user-sessions.service
    5ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
                 3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
```

Answer (score 0):

[DKMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) allows building out of tree kernel modules, you probably have something like nvidia drivers installed and this is an automatic rebuild after kernel update. Boot without the `rhgb quiet` kernel options and you should be able to see what is DKMS trying to rebuild, I don't think it is stuck, it just takes some time to rebuild the module.

Comment: thanks for your reply, you are right i have nvidia drivers installed. Before the DKMS message, I have `Stopped Light Display Manager` and then `Starting Light Display Manager` i don't know if it is normal. For 20 min it show `A start job is running for Builds a... rough DKMS` Do you have any idea how long does it take to rebuild it?

Comment: 20 minutes is really long. Does booting without the `quiet` option show something more? If it is really stuck forever, solution would be to boot in [recovery mode](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Rescue_Mode/) and disable dkms service.

Comment: Hi Vojtech, after 1h30 getting stuck on the DKMS message, my centos7 finally booted. I don't really know what happened. I will keep in mind to disable DKMS service if it redoes the same.

Comment: It seems even if KDE starts DKMS tried to build in backend. `su root` takes a longtime before login. Each reboot i have the same issue.

Comment: This now looks like a different probelm. Check logs there might be some helpful errors. Also run `systemd-analyze blame` to see what took so long during the boot.